# Increase speed of dynamic API calls using PHP

Tags: php, caching, memcached, pagespeed

I am calling different API's on one of my web sites. I am able to get optimal results with multi curl PHP. However, I'm noticing that the speed becomes very slow when traffic is a little high. I have read that caching is another way to speed up websites. However,my question is that can I use caching when the API calls that I am using are entirely dependent on user based inputs?  Or is there any alternative solution to this.

Comment: You can include the parameters in the cache key, so if you've already cached a call with the same parameters, you don't need to go to the API.

Comment: Hey Barmar,Thanks for the prompt reply. Your solution looks perfect but is the same possible if I don't know the values of parameters. Since the values of the parameters will depend on the user. For eg. in this call api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?q=PHP&l=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=5&limit=8&fromage=&filter=&latlong=&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2 
if I don't know value of q (keywords) and l (location),  how will I cache it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The user sends the parameters to your PHP script. So before using `curl`, it can check for those parameters in the cache.

Comment: The values of `q` and `l` are in `$_GET['q']` and `$_GET['l']`. Why don't you know them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible that maybe 1 request is taking too long to load and as a result delaying other requests.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on what kind of task user perform with the data. Basically cache can be used for all tasks related to retrieving, querying data  and is not suitable for inserting, mutating or deleting data. There are many way to implement cache in your web application, but one of the easiest way is to use GET request for all user's requests that retrieve data only, and then configure the web server or a CDN to cache them.

Comment: Hi Thai, Thanks for for your prompt reply. I am using cache only for querrying purpose only, but the problem is that the request of user is changing. For eg. in this call -
api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?q=PHP&l=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=‌​5&limit=8&fromage=&f‌​ilter=&latlong=&co=u‌​s&chnl=&userip=1.2.3‌​.4&useragent=Mozilla‌​/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29‌​&v=2  values of parameters q and l are dynamic, so how can I cache it.

Comment: The requests cannot be all different, arent they ? There must be request that have the same query string, even if you inject userip and useragent into it (which should be avoided if it is not really necessary), for example, if one user keep reloading the page that display the results, then instead of fetching data from the Api, your website can just serve this user the cached result that he saw before.

Comment: These requests are actually different user search queries. So if 10 users are searching for 10 different things there will be 10 totally different search queries. For eg. one call  can be api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?q=PHP, some other can be api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?q=Java and so on.There will be such calls for 6 different API's. This is the situation where program is becoming extremely slow.  My concept of cache says to save some highly used data on server. But how can I save such data for different queries? Also is there any other alternative to speed up?

Comment: If two querries are different, how can you share the results, it is just too costly trying doing something like that. Instead, what you want to do is , and what cache should be used is if user A and user B have the same input query string, for example q=a, they should receive the same result, that result is what you need to cache. There are plenty caching techniques can be used in this situation, and most modern webserver (like nginx) can cache the response for you for GET request with same query string. Otherwise, you can use an in memory cache as Memcache, Redis, etc... or a file cache.